# python wsgiref auto reload

Tags: python, wsgiref

I try to use `wsgiref` as a server like below:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Application(control)
    run = make_server('', 5000, app)

    print('Demo server started http://localhost:5000')
    run.serve_forever()
```

I want to use **auto reloading** for entire of my code. what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

you can use nodemon to auto reload python files when you make changes in your file:

Example:

```
nodemon main.py
```